# SQL Server - Replace money numbers with text

Tags: sql-server

I need to replace a money number with text. For example if it were 66.35 it would be displayed as 66 dollars and 35 cents.

This is what I got to display but I don't know how to replace the decimal with the word dollars.

```
SELECT Freight, CAST(Freight AS varchar) + ' cents' AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Orders
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEy9m.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the parts before and after decimal, cast each as varchar and then add in the text, like so:

```
SELECT Freight, 
cast(cast(floor(Freight) as decimal(2,0)) as varchar) + ' dollars and ' + cast(cast(100*(Freight - floor(Freight)) as decimal (2,0))as varchar) + ' cents'
FROM dbo.Orders
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am trying to get rid of the decimal and the 0's. For example I need it to be displayed as 32 Dollars and 38 cents.

Comment: Yeah, realised I missed that earlier. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! I still have one more problem. The dollars is being displayed as 32.00. How would I get it so it can only display the numbers to the left of the decimal?

Comment: I'm not seeing that when I try the code, but you can cast it to `decimal(2,0)` similar to how I did it for the cents part.

Comment: I'm trying to add that part, but I'm getting a syntax error. Would I input it as Freight, CAST(FLOOR(Freight) AS decimal(2,0) AS varchar)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, you are casting something to one type, then casting the result of it to another type, so it should look like `(cast(cast(x) as a) as b)`

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you so much! - EDIT. When I use that, my result set goes from 830 to 7. I believe its because some of the numbers have a different amount of digits to the left. EDIT2 - I was able to fix it by using (4,0) instead.